# Create Background-blurred RoundedRectangle in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using this code to create a background-blurred view:

```
struct Blur: UIViewRepresentable {
    let style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .systemUltraThinMaterial

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        return UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        uiView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    }
}
```

However, this code returns a regular rectangle with background blur. How do I make it rounded?

Comment: It would be better approach to round it outside than inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create another SwiftUI view:

```
struct BlurCircle: View {
    var body: some View {
        Blur()
            .clipShape(Circle())
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        BlurCircle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just do:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Blur()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .clipShape(Circle())
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want to do this *outside* the `Blur` struct, you can take a look at this answer:

- [How can UIVisualEffectView be used inside of a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392465/how-can-uivisualeffectview-be-used-inside-of-a-circle)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change 2 properies of your visual effect view, `cornerRadius` and `clipsToBounds`. Your `makeUIView` function would look like

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
    let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))

    view.layer.cornerRadius = 12  // change this to your radius
    view.clipsToBounds = true

    return view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

‘ struct BlurRectangle: View {
var body: some View {
RoundRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
.background(Blur())
.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
}
} ‘
Hope it’s helpful